# Where to find definitions of pre-build images of SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to build on top of the SageMaker pre-built image `sagemaker-base-python-310` (listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-images.html)). For example, start from pre-built image and add additional requirements to it.

Who could point where to find the definition of the container underlying such image (e.g. DockerFile)?

**What I tried**

- Searched on AWS GH Repos
- Searched in ECS

Comment: You can find all docker images by region at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-algo-docker-registry-paths.html

Comment: Thank you but this does not address the question of where to find the image sagemaker-base-python-310. Instead, the link you shared contains the images for relevant Machine Learning Algorithms (e.g. XGBoost). Any other idea?

Comment: I think the images you @Seymour looked for which I found similar at this [repo](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-example-notebooks-testing) 

- https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-example-notebooks-testing/blob/d2be59bb74656cc207b18acf95edd8846ef5e687/cdk-project/lib/image-stack.ts#L42-L109

After you login to **ECR** then you can pull it 
`aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 236514542706.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
then 
`docker pull 236514542706.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-base-python-environment:1.0
`

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Studio images aren't available publicly. The DLC based images (such as Pytorch, TF, etc.) are essentially built on top of the frameworks (see https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers), but Base Python, Data Science etc. are not open source.

If you're looking to add packages and such as part of customization, I'd recommend using LCC scripts.